# Retrieve all embedded Handlebar variables from a given text

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js

I'm working with the Handlebars library and developing on a function to retrieve all embedded variables. The function works with simple, non-logic, text. However, when there is if-statement the function only returns a subset of the varibles.

```
import Handlebars from "handlebars";

function getHandlebarsVariables(input){
    const ast = Handlebars.parseWithoutProcessing(input);
    return ast.body
      .filter(({ type }) => type === 'MustacheStatement')
      .map((statement) => statement.params[0]?.original || statement.path?.original);
};

const text1 = '{{name}} {{age}} {{#if isAdult}} {{ Adult }} {{/if}}';

const variables = getHandlebarsVariables(text1);

console.log(variables); // currently returns ['name', 'age'], I want to return ['name', 'age', 'Adult']
```

What I expect the function to return: ['name', 'age', 'Adult']
Currently I get: ['name', 'age']

Comment: To begin with, the Abstract Syntax Tree you get from `Handlebars.parseWithoutProcessing(input)` is a _tree_ - so you are likely going to need recursion to parse further down the tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is more to a compiler than you are giving it credit for. Your filter and map logic would be sufficient if the parsed Handlebars template were a simple, flat Array; but such a Syntax Tree is not that - it has many levels which must be parsed using recursion.

I am offering the code below, not as a fully-functional, shippable program, but just as an example of how you could recursively traverse the Syntax Tree. This example works for the `text1` input in your post, but I *would not* count on it to work for all Handlebars templates.

```
import Handlebars from "handlebars";

function getVariablesFromStatementsRecursive(statements) {
  return statements.reduce((acc, statement) => {
    const { type } = statement;

    if ("BlockStatement" === type) {
      const { inverse, program } = statement;

      if (program?.body) {
        acc = acc.concat(getVariablesFromStatementsRecursive(program.body));
      }

      if (inverse?.body) {
        acc = acc.concat(getVariablesFromStatementsRecursive(inverse.body));
      }
    } else if ("MustacheStatement" === type) {
      const { path } = statement;

      if (path?.original) {
        acc.push(path.original);
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
}

function getHandlebarsVariables(input) {
  const ast = Handlebars.parseWithoutProcessing(input);

  return getVariablesFromStatementsRecursive(ast.body);
}

const text1 = "{{name}} {{age}} {{#if isAdult}} {{ Adult }} {{/if}}";

const variables = getHandlebarsVariables(text1);

console.log(variables); // [ 'name', 'age', 'Adult' ]
```